# Implementation of quantum adder

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction

I'm looking at [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0511.pdf) paper and try to implement the Quantum adders they define myself.

Suppose we have a number $b=b_{n-1}\dots b_1b_0$ and they want to add a constant number $a=a_{n-1}\dots a_1a_0$.

They define
$$A_j = \Pi_{k=1}^{j+1} R_k^{a_{j+1-k}}, \quad R_k = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&e^{i2\pi/2^k}\end{pmatrix}$$

The result can be obtained by first applying a QFT on all qubits, then apply $A_j$ on qubit $j$ and then apply an inverse QFT.

However, if I try to work this out for the simple case where $b=0$ and $a=1$, I end up with a quantum state 
$$0.5\left|01\right> + (0.5+0.5i)\left|10\right> - 0.5i \left|11\right>.$$
Note in this case, $A_0 = Z$ and $A_1 = S$.

Is there an error in my calculation, or is the definition in the article not correct?

Comment: I *think* that both times you only apply the QFT or its inverse to the register b, not to a.

Comment: We only have a register $b$, as $a$ is a constant number and hence just an input.

Comment: Ah, sorry, so you're meaning $b=00$ and $a=01$?

Comment: Yes. The $a$ is constant and is not related to the QFT

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the steps that you've done in the calculation? At start, after QFT, after application of $A_j$, and at end?

Comment: [Here is the circuit in a simulator](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B"cols"%3A%5B%5B"Counting4"%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4"%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C"Chance4"%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C"QFT4"%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%E2%85%9B%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22QFT%E2%80%A04%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Chance4%22%5D%5D%7D). Is that helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming an initial state of the form $|a\rangle|b\rangle = |1\rangle|0\rangle$ for your simple case.  You first perform a QFT on the right qubit, obtaining $|1\rangle(\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$.  Next, you apply $A_0 = R_1$ to the right qubit to obtain $|1\rangle(\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$.  Finally, you apply an IQFT to the right qubit and obtain $|1\rangle|1\rangle$, thereby demonstrating that $1+0=1$.  As @DaftWullie noted, all the action happens on the "$b$" qubit; the $a$ qubit (or cbit in this case) acts only as a control.

Comment: This is not what I wanted to do. See the comments. Interchanging the gates did solve it.